# GCC installation Error

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, makefile

I am trying to install GCC 4.9.0, I got following errors for './configure' and 'make'.

I got following error for `./configure`

```
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
/usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: error: I suspect your system does not have 32-bit developement libraries (libc and headers). If you have them, rerun configure with --enable-multilib. If you do not have them, and want to build a 64-bit-only compiler, rerun configure with --disable-multilib.
```

Then I used `./configure --disable-multilib` then configure completed with out any error.

After 'make'; i end with following error and i am not able to identify what is this error

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/root/dsk/gcc-4.9.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/dsk/gcc-4.9.0'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/dsk/gcc-4.9.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help

Comment: Have you tried following the advices on this link: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#configure_suffix ? What is in config.log?

Comment: Avoid building GCC in its source tree.

Comment: same error repeated even after building from relative path ../configure

Comment: log file errors; conftest.cpp:11:2: error: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif

Comment: Also conftest.c:10:25: error: isl/version.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Would you care to give more information about building gcc in its source tree?  Such as a link to documentation?

Answer (score 8):

It seems you are missing gcc-multilib.

Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` and then run `./configure` again.

Answer (score 7):

For Centos you need to install following libraries:

```
sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686
sudo yum install libgcc.i686
```